# Calendar not displays events, no errors

Tags: reactjs

I've tried to use fullcalendar to display events and don't have idea why it's not working. Maybe I've something wrong in getData method, how do you think and console.log is empty.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button, Row, Col, Modal } from "antd";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction"; // needed for dayClick
import allLocales from "@fullcalendar/core/locales-all";
import get from "lodash/get";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/id";

const Cal = () => {
    const calendarComponentRef = React.createRef();
    const [calendarWeekends, setCalendarWeekends] = useState(true);
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    const [calendarEvents, setCalendarEvents] = useState([]);
    const [eventDetail, setEventDetail] = useState({});
    const getData = async () => {
          const requestOptions = {
                  method: "GET",
                  headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization:
                      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tokenType")) +
                      " " +
                      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accessToken")),
                  },
                };
        await axios
         .get("/events", requestOptions)
            .then(res => {
                const { data } = res;
                const callendarData = data.items.map(item => {
                    return {
                        title: item.username,
                         start: get(item, "startTime", ""),
                         end: get(item, "finishTime", ""),
                        backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
                        borderColor: "#ff0000"
                    };
                });

                setCalendarEvents(callendarData);
            });
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);
    console.log(calendarEvents);

    const toggleWeekends = () => {
        setCalendarWeekends(!calendarWeekends);
    };

    const handleDateClick = arg => {
        setOpenModal(true);
        setEventDetail({
             title: arg.event.title,
                  start: moment(arg.event.start).format("h:mm:ss a"),
                  end: moment(arg.event.end).format("h:mm:ss a"),
        });
        
    };

    const handleOk = () => setOpenModal(false);
    const handleCancel = () => setOpenModal(false);

    return (
        <div className="demo-app">
            <div className="demo-app-calendar">
                <Row style={{ paddingTop: "50px", paddingBottom: "50px" }}>
                    <Col>
                        <div className="demo-app-top">
                            <Button onClick={toggleWeekends}>
                                toggle weekends
                            </Button>
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; (also, click a date/time to add an
                            event)
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <FullCalendar
                            defaultView="dayGridMonth"
                            header={{
                                left: "prev,next today",
                                center: "title",
                                right:
                                    "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek"
                            }}
                            plugins={[
                                dayGridPlugin,
                                timeGridPlugin,
                                interactionPlugin
                            ]}
                            ref={calendarComponentRef}
                            weekends={calendarWeekends}
                            events={calendarEvents}
                            eventClick={handleDateClick}
                            locales={allLocales}
                            locale={"id"}
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Modal
                    title="Basic Modal"
                    visible={openModal}
                    onOk={handleOk}
                    onCancel={handleCancel}
                >
                    <p>Event : {eventDetail.title}</p>
                    <p>Tanggal Mulai : {eventDetail.start}</p>
                    <p>Tanggal Berakhir : {eventDetail.end}</p>
                </Modal>
            </div>
            {console.log(typeof eventDetail.start)}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Cal;

endpoint: /events
    [
        {
            "username": "alex",
            "startTime": "2020-07-27T13:30:00.000+00:00",
            "finishTime": "2020-07-27T15:30:00.000+00:00"
        },
    {
            "username": "john",
            "startTime": "2020-07-27T13:30:00.000+00:00",
            "finishTime": "2020-07-27T15:30:00.000+00:00"
        }
    ]
```

I've tried to use fullcalendar to display events and don't have idea why it's not working. Maybe I've something wrong in getData method, how do you think and console.log is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed getData function and set the event start date with Date Function with  and its working super fine. May be you have to change the event to an array of objects.I think it is about the changing the data coming from the api to array of objects having events.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction"; // needed for dayClick
import allLocales from "@fullcalendar/core/locales-all";
import get from "lodash/get";
import "@fullcalendar/core/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css";

const Cal = () => {
    const calendarComponentRef = React.createRef();
    const [calendarWeekends, setCalendarWeekends] = useState(true);
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    const [calendarEvents, setCalendarEvents] = useState([]);
    const [eventDetail, setEventDetail] = useState({});
    const getData = async () => {
              setCalendarEvents( [{ title: "Event Now", start: new Date() }]) 
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);
    console.log(calendarEvents);


    const handleDateClick = arg => {
        setOpenModal(true);
        setEventDetail({
             title: arg.event.title,
             start: new Date(),
              end:new Date(),
        });
        
    };

    return (
        <div className="demo-app">
            <div className="demo-app-calendar">
               
                        <div className="demo-app-top">
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; (also, click a date/time to add an
                            event)
                        </div>
                   
                        <FullCalendar
                            defaultView="dayGridMonth"
                            header={{
                                left: "prev,next today",
                                center: "title",
                                right:
                                    "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek"
                            }}
                            plugins={[
                                dayGridPlugin,
                                timeGridPlugin,
                                interactionPlugin
                            ]}
                            ref={calendarComponentRef}
                            weekends={calendarWeekends}
                            events={calendarEvents}
                            eventClick={handleDateClick}
                            locales={allLocales}
                            locale={"id"}
                        />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Cal;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can set callendarData in the below mentioned way

```
 const callendarData = data.items.map(item =>
               ({ 
                         title: item.username,
                         start: get(item, "startTime", ""),
                         end: get(item, "finishTime", ""),
                        backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
                        borderColor: "#ff0000"  
                }))
```

Comment: Thanks for advice Ahmad, but still I get undefined

Comment: if you can set this file in sandbox and share the link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-frog-yfusl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Endpoint: /events
    [
        {
            "username": "alex",
            "startTime": "2020-07-27T13:30:00.000+00:00",
            "finishTime": "2020-07-27T15:30:00.000+00:00"
        },
    {
            "username": "john",
            "startTime": "2020-07-27T13:30:00.000+00:00",
            "finishTime": "2020-07-27T15:30:00.000+00:00"
        }
    ]